# Chinese Collage Pictures made with paper, bamboo & Feathers (Characters identified: 松楓 沈陽)

Tags: character-identification, seal, calligraphy

[image]

We have a set of 3 collages bought from Hong Kongaround the 1970’s.  Do you know who the artist is please?

Comment: artist? well, at that time in hong kong, products targeted for tourists are not made by one artist. think about a “product line“. one skilful craftsman made part one, then send it to another skilful craftsman to make part two, etc . . . until it’s sold in a gallery 

Comment: Oh thank you, that’s very interesting.  They are very beautiful.  Much appreciated

Comment: By the way the picture is very impressive and beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Just so that there's no confusion about the character shape in the seal, which is 「陽」 and not 「揚」. See the third shape below:

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image: 陽]
[前](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)5.42.5
[合集14855](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=14855&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 陽]
農卣
[集成5424](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5424&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image: 陽]
虢季子白盤
[集成10173](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10173&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image: 陽]
法57
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image: 陽]</kbd>

The left-hand-side component of the character is [「阜・阝」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1095) rather than [「手・扌」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=129). There is a fair amount of fading around the middle of the character.

Answer (score -1):

In general, the name of the artist is written in the seal.
In the photos you took, the font of the seal is 小篆(Small Seal Script /Xiao Zhuan, an archaic form of Chinese calligraphy). Since it was a little blurred, I'm not 100% sure but I think its 沈扬, not 沈阳. 
I tried to google this person's name, but unfortunately, I didn't find any useful information about this person/artist.
In my opinion, there are two possibilities: maybe he/she is a well-known artist and since it's a picture you bought 50 years ago. It's hard to figure out who he/she is.
Or, as 水巷孑蠻 said, its just a picture from “product line“, even the seal may be not true.
But this is still a beautiful picture with memories, isn't it?